# Genering dedicated urls with slugs

Tags: python, django, django-views, url-routing, slug

I asked in past time about how generate an url with similar caracterist starting from an ID you said me that is better use slugs to do that. On this time I wanna generate dinamics urls with slugs. My objective is obtain this result:

I have five products that I named cards in models.py (Ysera, Neltharion, Nozdormu, Alexstrasza, Malygos). I need the respective url of each of the products:

localhost:8000/card/ysera

localhost:8000/card/neltharion

localhost:8000/card/nozdormu ... etc.

I try to generate these urls but i dont know if I made a good applying of commands, either I don't know how I can specify the id card like the main name of the card (ysera, neltharion...). I was trying to follow an answer posted here in this community a little blind and this is my "reconfiguration":

Here my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from dracoin.apps.synopticup.models import card
from dracoin.apps.home.forms import ContactForm,LoginForm
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def shop(request):
    tarj = card.objects.filter(status=True)
    ctx = {'tarjetas':tarj}
    return render_to_response('home/shop.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def singleCard(request, slug, id):
    try:
        tarj = card.objects.get(slug=slug, id=id_tarj)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        tarj = get_object_or_404(card, id=id_tarj)
        return render_to_response('home/singleCard.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My urls.py (I have an urls.py by app and the main urls.py):

```
url(r'^card/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<id_tarj>\d+)/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.singleCard',name='vista_single_card'),
```

My models.py:

```
class card(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

My common template for all cards:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Tarjeta {{card.nombre}} {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h1>{{ card.nombre }}</h1><br> 
<p> {{ card.descripcion }}</p>        

{% endblock %}
```

I don't know if my slug building in views.py was find, I'm convinced that the urls.py is bad but i don't know how build it?

please excuse me if I edit my own question to prolong it, Recently I'm trying to learn django by my side and I have many gaps in my learning

apologizeme in advance my extensive question and if I overlook something.

Thanks!!

Comment: 1) It seems like you don't have the field named “slug” on your card class. 2) Do you get an error message? If something doesn't work, you should better describe how it fails :)

Comment: beyond to describe an error, I wanna know what parts of my configurations have failures or on the other hand what I ignore to put. I know that I have many erros in my configuration, I try to follow two answers here but this is my result :(

Comment: Just an advice: try starting questions like this with a specific error message, and include your code as extra information. In your case it seems you have forgotten to include the [slug field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) in your model definition. (You're trying to get a card by its slug, but your card model doesn't define the slug field.)

Comment: Otherwise you're asking to do a code audit, which may be more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`tarj = card.objects.get(slug=slug, id=id_tarj)`

tries to load a `card` object where the `id` field is set to is `id_tarj` and the `slug` field is set to `slug`. Your model does not have a field named `slug`. You will need to add one.

A good candidate for it would be a `SlugField` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

You will need to make sure that your slug field contains a proper value in each case.